# How to print every error using try except in python

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I'm now learning how to handle multiple errors in python. While using `try-except` I want to print every error in `try`. There are two errors in `try` but the indexing error occurred first, so the program can't print a message about `ZeroDivisionError`. How can I print both `IndexError`message and `ZeroDivisionError`message?

Below is the code I wrote.

```
try:
    a = [1,2]
    print(a[3])
    4/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print(e)
except IndexError as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `IndexError` occurs, it goes to the `except`, so the `4/0` is not executed, the `ZeroDivisionError` doesn't occur, to get both executed, use 2 different try-except

```
try:
    a = [1, 2]
    print(a[3])
except IndexError as e:
    print(e)

try:
    4 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print(e)
```

Giving

```
list index out of range
division by zero
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that, when the first error occurs, your code executes `except` block unless you define multiple `try-except` blocks.